# I can't use mobilenet on my tensorflow project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow

Hello i want to make a tensorflow project for my school programming project so i'm trying to make a food classification program for android

But I have a problem.I trained 2 graph mobilenet and inceptionV3.I can use easily inception models but its slow but when ı want to use mobilenet retrained model i had a problem in android-studio

I chance input and output names via optimize_for_inference.py and I had a error like this

E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input], outputs:[final_result]

how can i solve

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: @vinS ı chanced now and i think i delete the mobilenet graph so i cant show but i have a error like this                
                                                                  
E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input], outputs:[final_result]

Comment: Without a stack trace this will be hard to debug